# How to create our own model for sentiment analysis using naive bayes classifier in mahout?

Tags: java, machine-learning, mahout, sentiment-analysis

I am a beginner in mahout. i don't know how to create our own model for sentiment analysis using naive bayes classifier in mahout. I want to create my own model to do sentiment analysis on top of some log data. Is there a step by step procedure for doing this. Like what are the classes we have to implement and  how to create model or how we can use existing models in mahout. Any help would be appreciated.
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/jpatanooga/sea-hug-navebayes24042011v5) a good guide about the steps to follow for an analysis using Naive Bayes classifier in Mahou. It's kind an step by step procedure.

> A Deep Dive into Classification with Naive Bayes. Along the way we take a look at some basics from Ian Witten's Data Mining book and dig into the algorithm....

Comment: Here is what i have done till now. 
1. Created train dataset manually.
 file content is like this...
 Positive product is very good
negative poor product
neutral Am ok with this product.

2. converted this file to sequence file and then to vector.

after this am not sure whether i have to give this training data to existing naive bayes in mahout or i have to create a new one using naive bayes for classifying data..

Comment: thanks emecas... i created the training data manually, but i don't know how to convert every line in the train data to sparse vector. seq2sparse command converts whole the file into vector. i want to convert each and every line.
Here is what i have done. i don't know what is wrong in it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540387/how-to-vectorize-text-file-in-mahout

Answer (score 0):

So did you look at the [quickstart](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Quickstart)?

The first step is to asses your corpus. How is your log data labeled? How much data do you have? If you have a labeled corpus then just follow the quickstart and substitue your corpus for the ones in the example.

Before you even start to write code you have to have a high quality corpus. Ensure that your examples are balanced and that you have enough data to train on. You can take a look at some research corpora for a general idea on what is required to train. I would sugest the Reuters-21578 corpus or if you can get it the RCV-1 corpus.

Comment: my log data is unstructured and unlabeled.  i want to classify the comment into positive, negative and neutral, am not sure whether i can use the existing naive bayes model in mahout or i have to create a new one.

Comment: You have to have a labeled dataset if you want to use machine learning. Start by labeling your existing data and then train your classifier with the labeled data. You can then use the trained classifier on new unseen data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have created labelled data manually. for training mahout naive bayes with training set data we need to convert that data into sequenece and then to sparse. Seq2Sparse command converts the whole file, instead i want to convert each and every line into vector.pls help , how ican convert every line into vactor.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What do you mean you want every line into a vector? Do you mean the every line is actually a separate document? Did you read https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/creating-vectors-from-text.html

Answer (score 0):

Your can see the following blog, here step by step process explained in detail:
http://instantjavasolutions.blogspot.in/2014/10/how-to-train-my-own-model-using-mahout.html